# Como cargar una Imagen en delphi salvada desde c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, delphi, pascal

tengo una aplicacion en .net mvc y estoy tratando de guardar una imagen en un campo de la Base de datos, esto lo hace bien, el problema es que esta imagen posteriormente sera leida desde una aplicacion hecha en delphi, aqui en delphi usan blobfield, cuando la guardo en delphi sale la imagen negra completa, sin embargo si se crea de delphi y la leo desde la aplicacion .net mvc lo lee perfectamente:

Desde javascript creo el base64 de la imagen de esta forma:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
val = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,"");
```

en c# obtengo el base64 y obtengo el array bytes para insertarlo en la BD

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

como pudiera ayudarme con esto si alguien le ha pasado alguna vez.

Comment: cual es la db que usas para persistir la imagen en c# ?

Comment: si persistes ese byte[] que obtienes del FromBase64String() y generas un archivo fisico, puedes ver la imagen correcta?

Comment: no habia pensado en eso voy a probarlo y comento

Comment: pues con el arreglo de bytes genero la imagen en disco y sale perfecto, pero cuando lo guardo en la tabla en sql server, y esta es leida de la aplicacion desktop escrita en delphi, sale la imagen completamente negra.

Comment: si la guardas en sql server y la recuperas de alli usando c#, se obtiene correctamente? porque si es asi entonces no es problema del codigo .net o la db, sino que debe ser del lado de delphi

Comment: ¿Qué componente utilizas en Delphi para mostrar la imagen? Pregunto, porque si utilizas el viejo TDBImage, este solamente soporta imágenes en formato BMP. Puedes hacer el cambio _al vuelo_ para guardar un BMP en C# (lo menos aconsejable), o bien cambiar la parte de Delphi para soportar otros formatos de imagen.